# Update data from MYSQL, PHP to drop down button

Tags: php, mysql, get

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aMovie WHERE aName= '{$_GET['id']}'"); 
        $row=mysql_fetch_object($sql);  
}

<input type = "text" name = "name" value = "<?php echo $row->aC; ?>"/> 
<select name = "name" >
        <option value = "" <?php echo ($row->aC== "Deadpool") ? 'selected = "selected"': '';?>">Deadpool</option>
        <option value = "" <?php echo ($row->aC == "BATMAN VS SUPERMAN") ? 'selected = "selected"': '';?>">BATMAN VS SUPERMAN</option>
</select>
```

Assume that aMovie is my table name, and in my table there are aName and and aC. However, I would want to display aName which matches aC ["Deadpool" or "Batman Vs Superman"] and display it in the drop down button. It only works for the input type but not the drop down button.

Comment: you are putting "selected" inside "value".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<select>` should be like:

```
<select name = "name" >
<option value="Deadpool" <?=($rows->aC == "Deadpool" ? 'selected="selected"': '')?>>Deadpool</option>
<option value="BATMAN VS SUPERMAN" <?=($rows->aC == "BATMAN VS SUPERMAN" ? 'selected="selected"': '')?>>BATMAN VS SUPERMAN</option>
</select>
```

`selected="selected"` will use outside the `value` attribute.

**UPDATE:**

As @Maninderpreet-Singh mentioned, you also need to change `$row` to `$rows`.

Comment: Doesn't work, it will still display Deadpool though my data is Batman Vs Superman :(

Comment: @ikon: `var_dump($row->aC == "BATMAN VS SUPERMAN")` if its return true, than this will work..

Comment: It works for an input box, not the drop down. Drop down still sets Deadpool as the static value

Comment: @ikon: `var_dump($row->aC)` yout value is not equal to `BATMAN VS SUPERMAN`

Comment: @ikon: did u checked: `var_dump($row->aC == "BATMAN VS SUPERMAN")`

Comment: @ikon: check last UPDATE

Comment: @ikon: change `$row` to `$rows`

Comment: @ikon: glad to help u friend.

Answer (score 1):

try to change

```
<option <?php echo($row->aC== "Deadpool") ? 'selected = "selected"': '';?>  value="<?php echo $row->aC;?>">Deadpool</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this and you are using different variable in input

```
<input type = "text" name = "name" value = "<?php echo $rows->aC; ?>"/>
```

`$row` and `$rows` are different

```
  <option value = "<?php echo $row->aC; ?>" <?php echo ($row->aC == "Deadpool") ? 'selected':'';?>">Deadpool</option>
  <option value = "<?php echo $row->aC; ?>" <?php echo ($row->aC == "BATMAN VS SUPERMAN") ? 'selected': '';?>">BATMAN VS SUPERMAN</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type = "text" name = "name1" value = "<?php echo $rows->aC; ?>"/> 
<select name = "name2" >
        <option value = " <?php echo($row->aC); ?>" <?php echo($row->aC=="Deadpool")?'selected': '';?>>Deadpool</option>
        <option value = " <?php echo($row->aC);?>" <?php echo($row->aC == "BATMAN VS SUPERMAN")?'selected': '';?>>BATMAN VS SUPERMAN</option>
</select>
```

Comment: never take name="name"